# Is it possible to make single Spark context for multiple spark confs

Tags: java, apache-spark

Is it possible in a single spark application to create two spark contexts for  two different spark confs

As I have a spark conf created for reading data from gz file and another for reading data from cassandra.

Here is my code

```
 public class SparkCassandraDriver implements Serializable {
    private transient SparkConf conf;

    private SparkCassandraDriver(SparkConf conf) {
        this.conf = conf;

    }


    private void run() throws JSONException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        JavaSparkContext sc  = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        getDataFromCassandra(sc);
        sc.stop();

    }

    private void run1() throws JSONException, IOException, InterruptedException {

        JavaSparkContext sc  = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        getDataFromS3(sc);
        sc.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException, InterruptedException {

            //First Spark Conf
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.setAppName("Spark-Cassandra Integration");
        conf.setMaster("local");
        conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "IP");
        conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.native.port", "9042");
        conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.rpc.port", "9160");
        conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.timeout_ms", "40000");
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.read.timeout_ms", "200000");

            SparkCassandraDriver app = new SparkCassandraDriver(conf);
        app.run();

            //Second Spark Conf
        SparkConf conf1 = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkAutomation").setMaster("local");

        SparkCassandraDriver app1 = new SparkCassandraDriver(conf1);
        app1.run1();
        System.out.println("Both RDD has been generated");



    }
```

}

Or is there any way I can use a single spark context with two different spark conf objects

Comment: Can you have two engines configuration running on one car ?

Comment: Logically no , so I have to create two different spark contexts right, I had asked since In a single JVM only one spark context has to be used.

Comment: @eliasah While your point stands,  it is a tricky question ;)

Comment: You'll have to create different contexts, yes.

Comment: Hi Guys, is there any better way of doing it , than the above  written code.